# Raspberry PI Writing CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi

As part of a project, I am trying to use a Raspberry PI to capture WiFi networks and write it to a CSV file. If the quality of the signal is over 30/70  I want to capture all WiFi SSIDs and their relevant MAC address and record it.
The issue seems to be relevant syntax but I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
def wifiscan():
    ssid = []
    scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])
    curtime = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    ssid.append(curtime)

    for line in scanoutput.split():
      line=str(line)
      if line.startswith("Quality"):
        line=line[8:-25]
      if(line>30 and line.startswith("ESSID")
        line=line[7:-1]
        ssid.append(line)
    with open('/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Results/'+'test.csv','a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        csvwriter.writerow(ssid)
    print ssid
```

Update 1:
[image: This is the output that I am looking to capture from:]
Update 2:
[image: This is what happens with the updated code and the results out.]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxvT1ZFq05Q

Comment: What does `if (line>30 ...` mean? Do you possibly mean `len(line)`?

Comment: I am trying to check the quality, so if it outputs as 32/70 that it will be recorded as it's greater than 30.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It seems, however, like `line>30` and `line.startswith("ESSID")` are incompatible conditional arguments.

Comment: also, in line: `if(line>30 and line.startswith("ESSID")` you are missing a close parenthesis and a colon.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example of `scanoutput`.

Comment: FYI: Not related, but I recall Python's `csv` module had issues with Unicode support.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have updated the post with the output that I need to capture from, also fixed some of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to your code but i don't know exactaly what you want to accomplish nor what errors you are experiencing, I just fixed some logic an sintax.

As it is, the code will append the ssid data to your csv only if quality is better than 30.

Let me know if that is what you want.

```
def wifiscan():
    ssid = []
    scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])
    curtime = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    ssid.append(curtime)
    quality = 0
    essid = ""
    for line in scanoutput.split('\n'):
      line=str(line)
      if line.startswith("Quality"):
        quality=int(line[8:-25])

      if quality>30 and line.startswith("ESSID"):
        line=line[7:-1]
        ssid.append(quality)
        ssid.append(line)
        with open('/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Results/'+'test.csv','a') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
            csvwriter.writerow(ssid)
    print ssid
```

Note that the code is sensible to any change in the sintax of the input you provide.

Also, to avoid syntax change issues in your input, maybe you should read about regular expressions in python: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. It seems that this is only printing the time stamp so the quality never gets assigned a value.

Comment: I forgot to add `ssid.append(quality)`, i changed it now

Comment: Update the code to remove the parameters inside of split however was left with the below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Code/projectCodeNew.py", line 31, in <module>
    wifiscan()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Code/projectCodeNew.py", line 18, in wifiscan
    quality=int(line[8:-25])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Sorry, the split was not the error, i just forgot to append, if you can send the input in text format (maybe doing `print(scanoutput)` and copying it) it would help to test the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I have update the photos in the main question to show what it says. when I use the split with the ('/n') nothing appears however when I remove it, it runs but only outputs the quality.

Comment: i think i see what is happenning now, `quality = 0` was in the wrong 'scope'